# How to print multiple line on Bluetooth printer

Tags: android, cordova, printing, bluetooth, ionic2

I am trying to print Invoice using ionic app. I am using Epson LQ-50 printer and ionic Bluetooth printer plugin

https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

I can print single line perfectly. But cannot print multiple lines. I have tried all methods suggested in plugins documentations. I even tried to send POS command for line feed (0xOA) but It gives an error after printing first line.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @Sachintha! What is the error? How are you printing the first line? Adding these to the questions could help you get an answer quicker.

Comment: I have used `printText(successCallback, errorCallback, [string to print])` function from above mentioned plugin. String only accept new line character (\n) only at end. If new line character was in middle of the string printer gives an error and stop printing at first new line character found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this not a software issue. It was a hardware issue. Power is not enough for the printer. Printer need more and 6A to print properly. I only supplied 5A at the begin.